# what does this mean in Laravel 5.7 (validator contract)

Tags: php, laravel, validation

From the Laravel 5.7 upgrade guide:

> The Validator Contract Likelihood Of Impact: Very Low
>   The validate method was added to the Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator contract:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Run the validator's rules against its data.
>  * @return array
>  */
> public function validate();
> ```
>
> If you are implementing this interface, you should add this method to your implementation.

So? What does *add this method to your implementation* mean? I have some validation in my code like:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    // rules are placed here...
]);
```

and now PhpStorm yells *unhandled validation exception* ...

Comment: Can you provide the source link and clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that if you have your own implementation of `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator`, you need to implement this method because otherwise you'll end up with a `Fatal error` as you can see in [this snippet](https://3v4l.org/iQnhK). The default implementation of this contract is `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`.

Because you do not receive a fatal error, your issue must be somewhere else. Maybe your problem has to do with nested validation? There have been fundamental changes according to the upgrade guide. Or did you by any chance upgrade your PHP version as well?

Comment: .. no the problem was, apparently, in php docs on the function not mentioning `ValidationException`

Comment: But that's not new. It is also the reason why one normally uses `$validator->fails()` or `$validator->passes()` instead of `validate()`.

Comment: what difference does it make? validate() works for me.

Comment: Have a look [at the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php) and you'll see the difference. `validate()` is just calling `fails()` under the hood, but with the nice taste of throwing an exception. According to your comment, you don't really expected that. So no, I don't agree that _it is working for you_, sorry.

Comment: hmm Yes I was expecting that, but on laravel 5.6 PhpStorm was not whining about not having phpdocs